# Hypernym of academia, researchers and topic enthusiasts

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Could *academics* or *acads* be used to describe the university faculty as well as researchers? What is a better hypernym of academia, researchers and topic enthusiasts?

Comment: Do you want enthusiasts who are not associated with academic institutions?

Comment: Despite having recently argued on meta that the *reason* OP asks his question has no bearing on whether it should be closed, I'm voting to close this one after noting that OP is specifically looking for a 4-5 letter word. I'm not even going to speculate on the "sub-reason" for that requirement - the question is "too localised".

Comment: @FumbleFingers: yes, that does seem like a capricious attitude. But you can't 'unvote' from closing.

Comment: @Mitch: I kinda doubt there *is* a hypernym for the three categories OP has requested that's any shorter than his actual list of them in the question title. But the idea that we should be looking for one shorter than, say, 6 characters strikes me as a misuse of ELU's precious electronic ink on my screen!

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Yes, I agree that if the OP in the end wants some arbitrary letter limit, that is crazy. But by your argument in meta, that shouldn't matter (however much it annoys us), we should rather answer the answerable part of the question.

Comment: @Mitch: You're welcome to try, mate! So far as I'm concerned, *it's unanswerable*!

Comment: The 4–5 letter request is not in the question. It's found in a comment in the bottom of a locked filing cabinet stuck in a disused lavatory with a sign on the door saying “Beware of the Leopard”. So FF's argument doesn't fly with me. The question as posed is answerable (in principle, anyway) and not too localized.

Answer (score 4):

In common usage, *academics* are those in *academia* or the *academe*, essentially, institutions of higher education and research. I would argue that it is inappropriate to apply the term to independent researchers or those in non-academic institutions.

**Scholars** would encompass those who apply scholarly discipline to their research; I might call an economist working for a public policy think tank a scholar but not an academic. More generically, **experts** are those with extensive knowledge of a subject regardless of approach, credentials or institutional affiliation. **Authorities** are those to whom people defer regarding knowledge of a subject.

An **aficionado**, **connoisseur**, or **devotee** is one who has cultivated a fine appreciation, although it is more common to apply these terms to enthusiasts of tangible items (e.g. an eye for historical artwork) as opposed to a discipline or field of study (e.g. a mind for the history of art).

Particular fields or areas of interest may have their own specific terminology as well. A *Star Trek* buff, for example, is a *Trekkie*.

Comment: Expert (exprt) does the localized trick.

Comment: If brevity is the key, in IT we also say **SME** for "subject-matter expert."

Answer (score 2):

**Academics**  denotes academic subjects, courses and studies. 
**Academic** may denote a teacher in a college or university.
You may use **academia**  or **university** to refer to academic environment and/or community.

Answer (score 2):

The word [*academia*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/academia?q=academia) fits:

> **academia**, *noun* : the environment or community concerned with the pursuit of research, education, and scholarship

Academia encompasses faculty and researchers (who are often one and the same). In bygone days, academia may have included dedicated amateurs (in observational astronomy, for example), but it's less likely in these hyper-specialized times.

Given that a *[hypernym](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/Hypernym)* is a word that is **more** generic (as opposed to a *[hyponym](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/hyponym)*, which is more specific) WordNet's suggestions for [hypernyms for academia](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&r=1&s=academe&i=3&h=100100#c) include:

- **world**: *The world of motion-capture animation encompasses applications as diverse as Smeagol and EA MVP Baseball*.
- **domain**: *The seemingly abstruse domain of psychohistory has room for both giants like Hari Seldon and accidental tourists like Arkady Darell*.

Also consider this statement from Columbia University's Department of Astronomy & Astrophysics:

> Our community includes faculty, researchers, and students in
>   Astrophysics and Astronomy at Columbia, Barnard College, NASA Goddard
>   Institute for Space Studies, and the American Museum of Natural
>   History pursuing a wide range of theoretical, observational, and
>   experimental research.

Comment: Thanks Gnawme! Actually I needed to trim academia to somewhat around 4-5 letters retaining its meaning, I was wandering if `acads` could do the job & whther that would include the researchers!? because acads *seems* to be related to people who study..

Comment: I've never heard *acads* and wouldn't know what it means.

Comment: That would be problematic, as _academia_ and related words derive from Academus, who owned the estate where Athenian philosphers gatherered, and not some root word that began with _acad_. Why the space restriction?

Comment: @Gnawme: 'academia' doesn't include serious enthusiasts for me. 'Academia' includes (obviously) faculty, but maybe not so obviously researchers, those who may not be associated with a university but with a named institute or business such that they publish papers in academic journals.

Comment: "Acads" is certainly not a recognized abbreviation. If you just want a heading to put at the top of a column in space-constrained table or something like that, you can, of course, always invent an abbreviation and then put a note somewhere defining it.

Comment: @Mitch I revised my answer somewhat to reflect your concerns about enthusiasts. But I attended a school that had a heavy research emphasis, so faculty and researchers were often the same. Also, the definition I cited does state "environment or community," which would certainly include an affiliated research institute.

Comment: This answer would have eminently suited but for the fact that the OP seems to precisely distinguish between and reflect the inclusion of: academia as you define as well as the not quite academia, such as (unattached) research scholars, external members, 'enthusiasts'/ 'dedicated amateurs' and the many similar categories.

Comment: To clarify, the hypernym should clearly express the distinction and inclusion of the two classes.

Comment: @Kris Note that hypernyms are more _generic_, not more specific. See my expanded answer.

Comment: Did I imply more specific? I had meant a **broader** catergory: 'inclusion of the two classes'.